# how to make data from backend have breakline in frontend in vue?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, nl2br

i'm trying to achieve this.
supposely i have data in backend with

example: this data - `#ghost\n#mik\n#bro`

supposedly it is store in an array of an object

> [ {hash:"#ghost\n#mik\n#bro"} ]

i want to make the value of  `hash_tag to have breakline in display in frontend`.

supposedly i display it in frontend and i bind it in a p element

```
<p v-for="data in dataFromBackend" :key="data.id">{{data.hash}}</p>
```

this is the script to have breakline in javascript

```
 function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {
    if (typeof str === 'undefined' || str === null) {
        return '';
    }
    return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' +  '$2');
};
```

the function nl2br work if do like this

```
 {{nl2br("mik\nmik\nbro")}}
```

the output is

```
mik
mik
bro
```

but when is try the data from backend its not working

```
{{nl2br(data.hash)}}
```

its output plainly

```
#ghost\n#mik\n#bro
```

Comment: use v-html, <p v-for="data in dataFromBackend" :key="data.id" v-html="data.hash"></p>

Answer (score 1):

To leave a line break in FE that has `\n` in the text, you just need to add css as follows

```css
.text-pre-line {
   white-space: pre-line;
}
```

In template

```
<p class="text-pre-line">Hello\nworld</p>
```

Output will be as follows

```
Hello
world
```

Comment: this work when text is plainly written in a paragraph

Comment: It work when text stored in variable too, i tried:
`
<script setup>
const text = "#Hello\n#world"
</script>
<template>
  <p class="text-pre-line">{{text}}</p>
</template>
`

Comment: did you try calling object inside array

Comment: I tried, it worked as normal:

<script setup>
const texts = [{ hash:"#Hello\n#world" },{ hash:"#Hello\n#world2" },]
</script>
<template>
  <p v-for="text in texts" :key="text.hash" class="text-pre-line">{{text.hash}}</p>
</template>

Comment: oh maybe there's a problem with my code. anyways the data is from database. gonna uprove your effort. thanks mate